# accessing property inside complex JSON angular6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have object as below I would like to to access period property of signers array of object, here is my  code

```
"data": [{
        "period": {
            "timestamp": "1585038503232",
            "comments": "test",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        "firstName": "ll1",
        "lastName": "ll2"
    }, {
        "period": {
            "timestamp": "1ds3648",
            "comments": "test.",
            "status": "approved"
        },
        "firstName": "rr,
        "lastName": "zz"
    },
{
        "period": {
            "timestamp": "1ds3648",
            "comments": "test",
            "status": "approved"
        },
        "firstName": "rr,
        "lastName": "zz"
    }
]
```

I tried like below : but it does not work. please help.

```
for (let data in values.data[0].period) {
....
}
```

basically I want to check if period has status of approved I would like to check for comments property.

//EDIT

```
this.dtata.forEach((item) => {
      if(item.acknowledgement.status === 'refused'){
        return true;
      }
      else { return false;}

  })
```

this is keep going on loop even it returns true I mean meeting condition of refused and evenutally it return false.

Comment: Try to access by `data.forEach(item => item.period.status)`

Comment: solution by @Mridul should work. BTW your data will have an invalid json. `"rr` should be `"re"`

Comment: @MohanSingh, that maybe a typing error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) by status and later use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to check the comments:

```
data.filter(o=> o.period.status === "approved").map(x => console.log(x.period.comments));
```

Comment: I want to return true if status approved

Comment: According to your original question: "basically I want to check if period has status of approved I would like to check for comments property." My solution filter the status, and later you can loop over the relevant objects, you can change the console.log to "return true". Please let me know if it is clearer now

Comment: return this.values.signers.filter(o=> o.acknowledgement.status === "refused").map(x => "return true") ?

Comment: You need to remove the "",  but it is really not clear which result are you looking for? what are you planning to do with result of array of "true"s?

Comment: I want to loop through singers and check if any of period has status ="approved" return true; and using same logic i want to return comments of matching condition like pending.comments

Comment: I had used forEach but it keeps looping until it reaches last element and this is resulting into false return even it have been match before

Comment: So you can use my code this way: data.filter(o=> o.period.status === "approved").map(x => x.period.comments);

Comment: how if I want to return true if matches condition

Comment: works great if If sometime period object inside is not available what in that case ? thought it is available everytime, some occurrence might not be available

Comment: You can use this: object1.hasOwnProperty('property1').     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

Use some if you just want to know if any item in array has status approved and stop when you find the first one:

```
  return data.some(item => item.period && item.period.status === 'approved')
```

Comment: works great if If sometime period object inside data is not available what in that case ? thought it is available everytime, some occurrence might not be available